# C# error - Not all code paths return value

Tags: c#, class, methods

So guys I know that have another posts like this with this name,but the other posts didn't help me find some solution for my problem.
I have 1 Form and 4 Class with methods,and It's getting problem in the Class called Costs,that get's all the other 3 Class and put in him.
I will post here the four classes.

First Class - Alimentaçao

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Projeto_CustosViagem
{
    class Alimentaçao
    {
        private String descriçao { get; set; }
        private double valorTotal { get; set; }
        private String nomeRestaurante { get; set; }

        public Alimentaçao()
        {
            valorTotal = 0;
        }

        public void calcularDespesa(int qtdeRef)
        {
            valorTotal = qtdeRef * 18;
        }

        public void listarDespesa()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Descrição : " + descriçao + "Valor Total = " + valorTotal + "Nome do Restaurante : " + nomeRestaurante);
        }


    }
}
```

Second Class - Transporte

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Projeto_CustosViagem
{
    class Transporte
    {
        private double kmPercorrida { get; set; }
        private double valorPedagios { get; set; }
        private double valorTotal { get; set; }


        public Transporte() {
            kmPercorrida = 0;
            valorPedagios = 0;
            valorTotal = 0;
        }

        public void calcularDespesa()
        {
            valorTotal = (kmPercorrida * 8);
        }


        public void listarDespesa()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Km Percorridos : " + kmPercorrida + "Valor dos Pedagios : " + valorPedagios + "Valor Total : " + valorTotal);
        }

    }


}
```

Third Class - Hospedagem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Projeto_CustosViagem
{
    class Hospedagem
    {
        private String nomeHotel { get; set; }
        private double valorDiaria { get; set; }
        private int qtdeDiarias { get; set; }
        private double valorTotal { get; set; }


        public Hospedagem()
        {
            valorDiaria = 0;
            qtdeDiarias = 0;
            valorTotal = 0;
        }


        public void calcularDespesa()
        {
            valorTotal = (qtdeDiarias * valorDiaria);
        }

        public void listarDespesa()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nome do Hotel : " + nomeHotel + "Valor da Diária : " + valorDiaria + "Quantidade de Diárias : " + qtdeDiarias + "Valor total : " + valorTotal);
        }
    }
}
```

Four Class - Custos(where are the problem)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Projeto_CustosViagem
{
    class Custos
    {
        public double totalViagem(Alimentaçao A, Transporte T, Hospedagem H)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If you guys can help me,I will thanks.The problem says that not all code paths return a value.

Comment: How about reading the documentation on something trivial like this?

Comment: "not all code paths return a value" is one of the more obvious compiler errors...

Comment: If the words don't help you, be sure to note the number CS0161 (CS means C# compiler). MSDN should be able to tell you about C# errors. If you use an IDE, it might even look it up for you (try F1).

Comment: Well,I am sorry guys,I know that this question was kind of noob,haha,I didn't understand at first place,but this mistake will never happens more.So thanks for helping(or not xxbbcc and Leigh Shepperson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your method "totalViagem" doesnt return anything, you have set its return type as double but it returns nothing, therin lies your problem

Comment: Thanks,I didn't saw that mistake.I was doing everything that I didn't stop to look for the error.

Comment: Did you not get a file and line number along with the error? That should have narrowed it down considerably, and allow you to get there quickly by clicking on the error message in most IDEs.

Comment: Nope,I didn't get the number along with the error.And I am using Visual Studio 2013.